# How to add items in DropDownlist based on condition in InfoPath?

Tags: infopath

I have One  form, in which there is 1 Dropdown list that contains List of Months From January to December of current year 2013.

Now if I select any particular Month then, all the Dates(Only for Sundays) should be added in another DropDown List. (Event should be done on Change of month, if another month I select, sundays/dates should be added respective to the month).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. I have used this method in several forms and it sure has served me well.

1. Create an xml file like the one shown below: (Please follow the same format to complete the rest of the months and their dates as well)

   ```
   <MonthToDateFilter>

     <MonthToDate Month="January">1/6/2013 </MonthToDate>

     <MonthToDate Month="January">1/13/2013 </MonthToDate>

     <MonthToDate Month="January">1/20/2013 </MonthToDate>

     <MonthToDate Month="January">1/27/2013 </MonthToDate>

     <MonthToDate Month="February">2/3/2013 </MonthToDate>

     <MonthToDate Month="February">10/3/2013 </MonthToDate>

     <MonthToDate Month="February">17/3/2013 </MonthToDate>

     <MonthToDate Month="February">24/3/2013 </MonthToDate>

     <MonthToDate Month="March">....  </MonthToDate>
     ......

     <MonthToDate Month="April">..... </MonthToDate>
     ......

   </MonthToDateFilter>
   ```

   I'll save myself a ton of time and let you follow [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15945/How-to-create-dynamically-populated-dropdown-in-an) It's got all the necessary steps from start to finish. You probably want to name your fields `Month` and `Dates` or anything really that you find appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Working with your drop-down list

Select the cells that have the drop-down list.

Go to Data > Data Validation.

On the Settings tab, click in the Source box. Then do one of the following: If the Source box contains drop-down entries separated by commas, then type new entries or remove ones you don't need.

Hope This Helps.